# ZF: disable action helper viewRenderer

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework

In order to provide an ajax action I do the following:

```
    public function preDispatch()
    {
        if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::removeHelper('viewRenderer');
                Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->disableLayout();
        }           
    }
```

but the response comes with the following error:
script 'async/tax.phtml' not found in path (/var/www/app/trunc/application/views/scripts/:./views/scripts/)

Comment: put a die inside your if and see weather it stops flow of execution .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using the Ajaxcontext action helper ? http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch

```
// supposedly in your async controller
public function init() {
$ajaxContext = $this->_helper->getHelper('AjaxContext');
$ajaxContext->addActionContext('tax', 'html')
}
```

Then name your view "async/tax.ajax.phtml" and ensure that your ajax call ask for the html format.

That way you can even adapt your code to automatically respond with json, phtml or xml with the same controller/action.

Comment: Found the solution:
ajax requests were send without
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
header, and that is why Zend could not find out what to render.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you checked whether the file `tax.phtml` exists in `/var/www/app/trunc/application/views/scripts/` .
2. If exists , then in `tax.phtml` place `echo exit;` at the bottom of the file.

Comment: it only exists as a 'scripts/partials/tax.phtml' to render ajax request, doest not exist anywhere else.

Comment: You could make use of `$this->renderScript( 'views/tax.phtml' );`
but make sure the file is located in the path specified.